# Diagnostic Tools: Events window empty / blank (Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, Update 3)

Tags: visual-studio

When I run my code in debug mode and have my diagnostic tools window open, my event panes are blank (both the timeline and the events call stack window).  How can I fix this?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, Update 3.  Interestingly the event panes works on my older PC using another Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise installation, only its on update 2, not 3.  Maybe update 3 has a bug?

Answer (score 0):

A Co-Worker and I were experiencing this same issue.

It ended up being that the IntelliTrace had been disabled on the machine that didn't show any Event information.

Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace -> General